# Passar icon e nome no ng-options

Tags: html5, angularjs

Se alguém puder me ajudar, mas desde já agradeço!
Esse é meu código:

```
$scope.Moedas =[
          { id: 0, nome: "REAL", icon:"fas fa-dollar-sign" ,ativo: false },
          { id: 1, nome: "DOLAR", icon: "fas fa-dollar-sign", ativo: false },
          { id: 2, nome: "EURO", icon: "fas fa-euro-sign", ativo: false }      
        ];

<div class="form-group col-xs-6">
    <select class="" ng-model="Produto.moeda" ng-options="o.nome as o.nome | translate for o in Moedas" ng-enter="">
        <option value="" disabled>{{'SELECIONE_MOEDA' | translate}}</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Comment: No caso você quer usar os itens de **Modeas** como opções do select?

Comment: Isso eu tenho os itens nas opções quero colocar o o icone e o nome ao lado.